# Ionic App: Firebase test lab couldn't connect to server error, different APIs, no pattern

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-test-lab

On the google developer console my app (target API 23) had this issue with the HTC 1 (with API 19) and Galaxy S6 (API 22) running the error attached below when the console ran the prelaunch firebase. Then on my newest apk submission those two running the same APIs worked fine which doesn't make any sense.

Yet each test I've done seperately in firebase test lab comes up with one phone that does this as well. Xperia z5 (API 22) and Moto G (API 23). This doesn't happen on a physical android device I have.

In my android manifest my min is 16, my target is 23, and I set no max so it works on newer versions.

I also can't find a pattern on this issue.Therefore I'm stuck as to why this is happening?Does it happen for anyone else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to add this to your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```